# Mock patch unable to find the path

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm having some trouble mocking a function. It's throwing ValueError exception and not able to mock the attribute.

**Folder Structure**

```
root
     \api
         ProjectFolder
              ProjectDetails.py
      \GetProjectList
         main.py
         __init__.py
      \test
         test_projectList.py
         __init__.py
```

I am calling one function "**get_ProjectList**" from class "**ProjectList**" in **ProjectDetails.py** file. Here are other files.

**main.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from api.ProjectFolder.ProjectDetails import *

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Trigger function for get projects list.')

    response, status_code = ProjectList().get_ProjectList()
    return func.HttpResponse(response,status_code=status_code)
```

**test_projectList.py**

```
from unittest import mock
import unittest
from GetProjectList.main import *
import azure.functions as func

class Test_ProjectDetails(unittest.TestCase):    

    def test_ProjectDetails(self):
        with mock.patch('api.ProjectFolder.ProjectDetails.ProjectList.get_ProjectList') as mock_get:
        
             mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200
            
             req = func.HttpRequest(
                   method='GET',
                   body=None,
                   url='/GetProjectList'
                  )

             resp = main(req)

         expected_status_code = 200

         self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,expected_status_code)  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run this it throws exception saying **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)** from **main.py** and line at **response, status_code = ProjectList().get_ProjectList()**

**Ignore if indentation error while copying the code

Answer (score 0):

The line `mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200` makes the function's mock return only one value (integer 200).
In the main section, `response, status_code = ProjectList().get_ProjectList()` it is expected that `get_ProjectList()` will return 2 values.
I suggest you change the mock so it will return 2 values, for example:
 `mock_get.return_value.status_code = (200, 200)`,
and then the function's mock will return a tuple of 2 arguments (like returning 2 arguments from the original function), and the main code will have some second value to unpack.

Comment: I am getting the same error on passing a tuple of two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I got this done by the following changes in the test file.

```
from unittest import mock
import unittest
from GetProjectList.main import *
import azure.functions as func

class Test_ProjectDetails(unittest.TestCase):    

      def test_ProjectDetails(self):
          with mock.patch('GetProjectList.main.ProjectList.get_ProjectList') as mock_get:
    
               mock_get.return_value = (<message>,200)
        
               req = func.HttpRequest(
                     method='GET',
                     body=None,
                     url='/GetProjectList'
               )

               resp = main(req)

           expected_status_code = 200

           self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,expected_status_code)  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```